# Rails Form - Non-associative check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form for an object and it looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @my_object do |f|
  = f.input :attribute_1
  = f.input :attribute_2
```

Now one of the things this object has, is an array of operating systems, `['AIX', 'Linux']`, some might have `['AIX', 'Linux', 'SunOS']`, etc. I want to have a check box for each of these and when the form is submitted, it would just populate this array. I'm not really sure how to go about having the form modify an array with check boxes.

I have this constant in an initializer that I'd like to use for the check boxes.

```
PLATFORMS = %w(AIX Linux SunOS)
```

Note: I'm also not using `ActiveRecord` at all.

I don't currently want to make the Operating Systems its own object, so I don't want to have an association.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize it was this simple.

```
= f.input :my_array, as: :check_boxes, collection: PLATFORMS
```